# Shorten with multiple If else condition

Tags: java

I am trying to shorten my if else statement, i have a few approaches that i tried however, i still its too long. The orignal script that i wrote is show below

```
public static SqlType getSqlType(String metadata) {
        System.out.println("metadata info " + metadata);
        if (metadata.startsWith("string") || metadata.startsWith("char") || metadata.startsWith("varchar")) {
            log.logger.info(metadata + " to " + "varchar");
            return SqlType.text();
        }
        if (metadata.startsWith("bigint")) {
            log.logger.info(metadata + " : " + "bigint");
            return SqlType.bigInt();
        }
        if (metadata.startsWith("int")) {
            log.logger.info(metadata + " : " + "int");
            return SqlType.integer();
        }
        if (metadata.startsWith("smallint") || metadata.startsWith("tinyint")) {
            log.logger.info(metadata + " : " + "tinyint");
            return SqlType.smallInt();
        }
        if (metadata.startsWith("boolean")) {
            log.logger.info(metadata + " : " + "boolean");
            return SqlType.bool();
        }
        if (metadata.startsWith("float") || metadata.startsWith("double") || metadata.startsWith("decimal")) {
            log.logger.info(metadata + " : " + "decimal");
            return SqlType.doublePrecision();
        }
        if (metadata.startsWith("timestamp")) {
            log.logger.info(metadata + " : " + "varchar");
            return SqlType.timestamp();
        } else {
            log.logger.log(Level.WARNING,"Datatype is not declared in java class and is convert as text : " + metadata );
            return SqlType.text();
        }
    }
```

The **first** approach i tried was using is as follow

```
if(metadata.startsWith("string") || metadata.startsWith("char") || metadata.startsWith("varchar")){return SqlType.text();}
if(metadata.startsWith("int")){return SqlType.bigInt();}
```

using this approach will not enable me to include logger as it will too long winded too.

The second approach i tried is using ternary as follow

```
 return metadata.startsWith("string") || metadata.startsWith("char") || metadata.startsWith("varchar") ? return SqlType.text();
         : metadata.startsWith("string") || metadata.startsWith("char") || metadata.startsWith("varchar") ? SqlType.text();
```

However in the second approach , how add in the logger file as shown in example script above.  What is the best practices or approach should be taken into coding multiple if else conditions

Comment: This is probably a better question for <http://codereview.stackexchange.com>

Comment: Can you post part of the content of `metadata` ?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy , i didnt know stackexchange codereview exist. but thank you , moving forward i will ask on codereview instead .

Comment: Have a Map of `<String, SqlType>`  If you want the logging extend `SqlType` with a logging field

Answer (score 1):

Simplify if conditions is depend on the `metadata` and how you want to process in. But you can improve the code readability and make it simple  using `StringUtils`

Your code:

```
   if (metadata.startsWith("float") || metadata.startsWith("double") || metadata.startsWith("decimal")) {
        log.logger.info(metadata + " : " + "decimal");
        return SqlType.doublePrecision();
    }
```

StringUtils:

```
if (StringUtils.startsWithAny(metadata, "float", "double", "decimal")) {
     return SqlType.doublePrecision();
}
```